Is it possible to link the type of a `Map` key to its values?
The idea is to store typed callbacks within a Map using something like the following example (the types are incorrect, example meant to show intentions)
type Events = { type: 'e1' } | { type: 'e2' };
type AddListener = <const EventName extends Events['type']>(
  eventName: EventName,
  cb: (event: Extract<Events, { type: EventName }>) => void,
) => () => void;
const addListener: AddListener = (eventName, cb) => {
  type ListenersMap = {
    [key in Events['type']]?: Set<(event: Extract<Events, { type: key }>) => void>;
  };

  const listenersMap: ListenersMap = new Map(); // Incorrect types

  return function removeEventListener() {
    /* ... */
  };
};

(playground link)
Is there a way of linking the type of the keys of a map to its values to accomplish something like above?

Looks like two separate issues going on here, only one of which you're explicitly asking about. The one you're talking about explicitly is a duplicate of this question. The unmentioned issue has to do with hooking up generics in the right way for the inside of addListener to work without type assertions, which is the topic of ms/TS#47109. Fixing both gives you this code. See the linked q/a for more information.

Thank you @jcalz, wasn't aware of the two issues at play here, much appreciate the help with both
